# Google Street View: Redundancy between Maps and Publish API

Tags: google-street-view, google-streetview-publish

I am connecting spheres via Publish API which were formerly uploaded with the Street View App.

Although it sometimes takes several hours for the changes to be visible in Google Maps, most of the connections are working.

For one pano though the new connection won't be reflected in maps since a week.

For the pano `CAoSLEFGMVFpcE4zMEhBT3B6ZUxhd2pabVhpZHhZZnM4SlNvOHdEc0c5aWhqNHdZ` the second connection in Publish API is
`CAoSLEFGMVFpcE5OVTRwZWNsMUNnQkNuOF8zbnEtbWpGeWlxSlNoVDAwUHRKWjJs` (correct)
in Maps it is still
`CAoSLEFGMVFpcE1wS01kWk9zdjRuR2pYSEF1N09GMG1LaEhOR19PaDdTOGtoUGRD` (wrong).

Normally I'd just delete the connections and set new ones afterwards. But since that approach also led to wrong data (presumably due to caching?), I'm hesitant trying that again.

What could be the cause for this redundancy? What would be the least effort to correct this connection?

Answer (score 2):

Fyi, you don't need to delete connections and then set new ones. You can do these two operations in a single [photo.update](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rest/v1/photo/update) call.

As long as you include `photo.connections` in the `updateMask` of the `photo.update` call, then any new list of connections will replace the current list (even if the new list is empty or omitted). For example, if your current connections are `[A, B]`, and you call `photo.update` with `photo.connections` set to `[A, C]`, then technically you are removing connection B and adding connection C.

Comment: In a perfect world this is like it would be. In this case though that workflow has some bugs it seems.